# what happens if we define column lengths as more than required?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I had a friend tell me that never to declare varchar as (255) if we will be only using 20 characters. Same for an INT.

Performance wise, Is this true ? Can i achieve a performance gain by reducing the size of my columns ? What exactly happens when i declare a column as 255 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases there will be no performance gain with shorter `VARCHAR` columns.

1 of the cases where there will be a performance gains, If you have a `MEMORY` table - a in memory temp table, MySql will allocate memory for the length of the column.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html):

> MEMORY tables use a fixed-length
>   row-storage format. Variable-length
>   types such as VARCHAR are stored using
>   a fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

Using `TINYINT` instead of `INT` if you only need the size of a `TINYINT` will save a few bytes per row.

A `VARCHAR(255)` will not use more then a `VARCHAR(20)` if you always only use 20 characters ( `CHAR(255)` on the other hand might use more then `CHAR(20)` )